# Javascript/JqueryHow to check url address if its same as home page adress with variable country and language in address?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to check url address if its same as home adress. I mean url address is for example:

```
http://example.example.com/(two letter country)/(two letter language)/
```

or

```
http://example.com/(two letter country)/(two letter language)/
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/(two letter country)/(two letter language)/
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hostname and other variables you need from location.href:

```
var arr = location.href.split("/")
var hostname = arr[2];
var countryCode = arr[3];
var languageCode = arr[4];
```

Comment: Best answer. Easy to follow. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.URL` and compare it with the url that you have

Comment: What if i have in .htaccess hidden index.php in home page url ?